# How to Serialize Web Socket Frame.text in Ktor with kotlinx.serialization

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlinx.serialization

```kotlin
webSocket("/ws") {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    when(val frame = incoming.receive()){
                        is Frame.Text -> {
                            val text = frame.readText() //i want to Serialize it to class object
                            send(Frame.Text(processRequest(text)))
                        }
                        else -> TODO()
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                TODO()
            }
        }
```

i want to Serialize `frame.readText()` to return class object
i'm totally new to Ktor world and i don't know if that is possible

Comment: Could you please explain better what you have in your `text` variable? It's a JSON string? Or something else? If you have a JSON string you could use [`kotlinx.serialization`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the underlying `kotlinx.serialization` that you might have already set up for ContentNegotiation already. If you haven't, instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/README.md). This will require to make your class (I assumed the name `ObjectType`) serializable with `@Serializable`. More details [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serialization-guide.md) on how to make a class serializable and also how to encode/decode to JSON format. I included the solution snippet:

```
webSocket("/ws") {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    when(val frame = incoming.receive()){
                        is Frame.Text -> {
                            val text = Json.decodeFromString<ObjectType>(frame.readText())
                            send(Frame.Text(processRequest(text)))
                        }
                        else -> TODO()
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                TODO()
            }
        }
```

I would usually use a flow (requires `kotlinx.coroutines`)

```
incoming.consumeAsFlow()
        .mapNotNull { it as? Frame.Text }
        .map { it.readText() }
        .map { Json.decodeFromString<ObjectType>(it) }
        .onCompletion {
            //here comes what you would put in the `finally` block, 
            //which is executed after flow collection completes
        }
        .collect { object -> send(processRequest(object))}
```

Comment: **unresolved Reference: `decodeFromString`**

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky you need to import the inline function: https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx.serialization/decode-from-string.html